# computing an integral using an empirical integrand

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an empirical probability function `p(z)`. In the first column `z` and the second column contains `p(z)` values. The data is given as following :

**data.cat**

```
+0.01234 +0.002816
+0.03693 +0.003265
+0.06152 +0.003551
+0.08611 +0.006612
+0.1107 +0.008898
+0.1353 +0.01041
+0.1599 +0.01269
+0.1845 +0.01404
+0.2091 +0.01616
+0.2336 +0.01657
+0.2582 +0.01865
+0.2828 +0.01951
+0.3074 +0.02024
+0.332 +0.02131
+0.3566 +0.0222
+0.3812 +0.02306
+0.4058 +0.02241
+0.4304 +0.02347
+0.4549 +0.02461
+0.4795 +0.02306
+0.5041 +0.02298
+0.5287 +0.02212
+0.5533 +0.02392
+0.5779 +0.02118
+0.6025 +0.02359
+0.6271 +0.024
+0.6517 +0.02196
+0.6762 +0.02155
+0.7008 +0.02314
+0.7254 +0.02037
+0.75 +0.02065
+0.7746 +0.0211
+0.7992 +0.02037
+0.8238 +0.0198
+0.8484 +0.01984
+0.873 +0.01959
+0.8976 +0.01869
+0.9221 +0.01873
+0.9467 +0.01861
+0.9713 +0.01714
+0.9959 +0.01739
+1.02 +0.01678
+1.045 +0.01633
+1.07 +0.01624
+1.094 +0.01543
+1.119 +0.01494
+1.143 +0.01547
+1.168 +0.01445
+1.193 +0.01384
+1.217 +0.01339
+1.242 +0.01384
+1.266 +0.01298
+1.291 +0.0109
+1.316 +0.0122
+1.34 +0.0111
+1.365 +0.0109
+1.389 +0.009592
+1.414 +0.01114
+1.439 +0.0111
+1.463 +0.009061
+1.488 +4.082e-05
```

I have to compute the following integral using the empirical probability density by some kind of interpolation:

[image]

or it can be re-written as

[image]

where [image] is defined as

[image]

and *a* is given as

[image]

I am wondering how I could compute this complicated integral regarding the existence of an empirical probability density function in the middle?

Do I need to do some kind of interpolation?

Comment: You could try using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to get a continuous representation of your data,  then define analytically the integrand in a python function and finally use `scipy.integrate.quad` for the integration.

Comment: @rth but `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` doesn't return a function that can be used in the integrand, does it? I can only give an array and it returns its *interpolated* values.